# C# PowerModeChanged does not trigger always

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sleep

The problem I don't know the answer to...
So on app level I want to do something when PC wakes up from sleep, so on my class ctor I did this:

```
public MyClass()
{
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;
}
```

OnPowerChange method looks like this:

```
private async void OnPowerChange(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Mode);
    if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Resume)
        //Do something
}
```

So this event triggers only sometimes... For example when I run my app and go to sleep, when I wake - event fires. But now, when I go to sleep for the second time, after sleep, when I wake up nothing happens... `Debug.WriteLine` does not show anything, so the event is never fired... What could be the problem? How can I make `OnPowerChange` event work always?

Comment: There is **no problem here** with the code you've given. If there is any, it must come from any other part of your application. I also doubt that keeping the method asynchronous might be causing this. (*why?*) If you're running the application as a service, it's all fine, but if you're running it as an application, make sure you have a **logic/loop to keep the program running**. (This might be the reason why you're program works once alone(**await**), I can't say more without knowing the structure of the application).

Comment: well.. async is because I need to do call Tasks, but I don't think that async might be the problem... But who knows... It's microsoft.. You can expect anything from them :D

Comment: There's no other problem with the code, I've tried it and it works perfectly!